# Creating dynamic file name in python

Tags: python, ipython

I have written a function to create dynamic files and the file name will contain u 2 arguments that are passed to the function.

```
def formrequests(carrier,airport):
    s=requests.Session()
    r=s.get("http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx?Data=2")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    viewstate_element=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")
    viewstate=viewstate_element["value"]
    eventvalidation_element=soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")
    eventvalidation=eventvalidation_element["value"]
    r = s.post("https://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx?Data=2",
       data = (
           ("__EVENTTARGET", ""),
           ("__EVENTARGUMENT", ""),
           ("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate),
           ("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventvalidation),
           ("CarrierList", carrier),
           ("AirportList", airport),
           ("Submit", "Submit")
       )
   )
   f=open("C:\\Users\\JAYASHREE\\Desktop\\Data Analyst Nanodegree\\Data Wrangking with MongoDB\\carrier-airport data files\\%s-%s.html","w" %(carrier,airport))
   f.write(r.text)
```

While running this function it is throwing me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-3323d46461b0> in <module>()
      3 for carrier in carriers:
      4     for airport in airports:
----> 5         formrequests(carrier,airport)

<ipython-input-63-258f8611f601> in formrequests(carrier, airport)
     17                    ("Submit", "Submit")
     18                   ))
---> 19     f=open("C:\\Users\\JAYASHREE\\Desktop\\Data Analyst Nanodegree\\Data Wrangking with MongoDB\\carrier-airport data files\\%s-%s.html","w" %(carrier,airport))
     20     f.write(r.text)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Please let me know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The line with the `f=open` format string is incorrect. Maybe try:

```
f=open("C:\\Users\\JAYASHREE\\Desktop\\Data Analyst Nanodegree\\Data Wrangking with MongoDB\\carrier-airport data files\\{0}-{1}.html".format(carrier,airport),"w")
```

The arguments were beyond where they should be.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got the formatting wrong on that line. Change this:

```
f=open("C:\\Users\\JAYASHREE\\Desktop\\Data Analyst Nanodegree\\Data Wrangking with MongoDB\\carrier-airport data files\\%s-%s.html","w" %(carrier,airport))
```

to this:

```
f=open("C:\\Users\\JAYASHREE\\Desktop\\Data Analyst Nanodegree\\Data Wrangking with MongoDB\\carrier-airport data files\\%s-%s.html" %(carrier,airport),"w")
```